# How to test REST API which serve a .zip file using postman?

Tags: java, playframework, postman, rest

I have a REST API that is developed using the Java play framework. The API servers the ".zip" file as a response to the request.

Is there any way to test this API using postman? I need to check whether the ZIP file is served properly.

Comment: What's blocking you to test it with Postman?

Comment: I wanted the postman to download the zip file. I was not sure about how to do that. Now I found a way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @veysiertekin Sorry I missed your comment. While sending a request instead of "send" you can choose "send and download". or you can follow the first answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Save Response` button to save the file.

[image]